# Consultar DNI con JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

Buenas noches tengo este problema al realizar la consulta de un DNI desde esta página, espero que me puedan ayudar.Esta es la página a la que quiero acceder:

http://www.votoinformado.pe/voto/miembro_mesa.aspx

Este es mi código en Java:

```
  public static Document getHtmlDocument(String url){
      Document doc=null;
      FormElement form=null;
      HTMLDocument pag=null;
    try {
       doc=Jsoup.connect(url).data("txtCongrDNI","75624412").userAgent("Mozilla/56.0.1").timeout(10000).post();   
       //LO QUE QUIERO REALIZAR ES QUE ME MUESTRE LOS DATOS PERSONALES COMO EL NOMBRE Y APELLIDOS
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Excepción al obtener el HTML de la página" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Esto solo me devuelve el código fuente de la página:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, evita las mayúsculas a la hora de redactar preguntas o respuestas. Hacen que el texto sea más difícil de leer y, en Internet, escribir en mayúsculas es el equivalente a gritar (que no creo que sea el caso). Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y que edites la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te faltaron pasarle los elementos ocultos del formulario para que al momento de hacer POST obtengas la consulta correcta.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://www.votoinformado.pe/voto/miembro_mesa.aspx")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(loginForm.body());
        Elements tag = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]");
        String viestate = tag.attr("value");

        tag = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]");
        String viewstategerator = tag.attr("value");

        tag = doc.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]");
        String eventvalidation = tag.attr("value");

        Document finalDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.votoinformado.pe/voto/miembro_mesa.aspx")
                .data("txtCongrDNI", "75624412")
                .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                .data("__EVENTTARGET", "btnCongrDNI")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE", viestate)
                .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", viewstategerator)
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventvalidation)
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .post();


        String DNI =  finalDoc.select("span#lblDNI").text();
        String fullName =  finalDoc.select("span#lblNombres").text();
        System.out.println("The ID number is "+DNI); 
        System.out.println("The full name is "+fullName);
    }
}
```